# Cannot read property getPermissionStatus of undefined | react-native-permissions

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this error when calling Permissions.check() using the [react-native-permissions library](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions)

[image: getPermissionStatus error]

I'm using the code straight from the react-native-permissions README

```js
  componentWillMount() {
    Permissions.check('photo').then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

I used react-native link to link it.

```js
react-native link react-native-permissions
```

I'm pretty sure it's linked correctly because when I call Permissions.getTypes()

```js
componentWillMount() {
    console.log(Permissions.getTypes());
}
```

I get the following response:

[image: getTypes response]

**React Native Version:** 0.53.0

**React Native Permissions Version:** 1.1.1

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'myApp' do
  pod 'Stripe', '~> 11.2.0'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

  pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

end
```

**Edits**

- I downgraded React Native to 0.52.0 as that's the last react-native-permissions updated their README and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out,

```
Permissions.getTypes()
```

works without linking.

I ended up having to follow the manual linking instructions here: [using manual linking](https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions#user-content-using-manual-linking)

> **Using manual linking**
>
> ```
> In the XCode's "Project navigator", right click on your project's Libraries folder ➜ Add Files to <...>
>
> Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-permissions ➜ select ReactNativePermissions.xcodeproj
>
> Add libReactNativePermissions.a to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
> ```