# Using react-native-permissions I get this error when trying to build with xcode ld: library not found for -lPermission-LocationWhenInUse

Tags: react-native, react-native-permissions

I have tried manual linking as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49537545/9604547) but I still get the error `library not found for -lPermission-LocationWhenInUse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the below steps

go to ios folder from terminal, 
run 'pod install' or 'pod update'. 
Open ios/newproject.xcworkspace. 
Also do not forget to enter the permission strings for location inside your info.plist file

Comment: Hi @imjaad already done the pod install / pod update. this is a part of my info.plist `<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
 <string>????</string>
 <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
 <string>1</string>
 <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
 <true/>
 <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string/>
 <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
 <string>LaunchScreen</string>`

Comment: Please describe how are you trying to use this library and when do you get error,

Comment: it worked after opening ios/newproject.xcworkspace was previously running newproject.xcodeproj. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First run `react-natve link` , then `cd ios` and then run this command `pod install`
`cd ..` and `react-native run-ios`

Don't forget to install pods

Comment: i have done all this. even attempted to manually the link the library, but still getting the library not found for -lPermission-LocationWhenInUse error